# Cannot find module 'measuretool-googlemaps-v3'

Tags: npm, jestjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have a project created using 'create-react-app' and I have one import in one of the file like this

```
 import MeasureTool from 'measuretool-googlemaps-v3';
```

I am not facing any issue when I am running my project but when I am trying to run my test coverage using `npm run test` (`"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"`)

I am getting this error **Cannot find module 'measuretool-googlemaps-v3'**

This is my jest configuration in **package.json** file

```
"jest": {
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text",
      "cobertura"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!/node_modules/",
      "!src/index.js",
      "!src/registerServiceWorker.js",
      "!src/setupTests.js"
    ]
  }
```

It is giving error only for this package. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you provide a repo or codesandbox for reproducing the issue?

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems to me that the root of the problem is in ESM modules. They are not fully supported by the node itself (see more about it here - https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#differences-between-esm-and-commonjs), therefore we might encounter with such issues.

The package comes with 2 builds - ESM and UMD. I resolved my issue by explicitly mapping module path to UMD version:

```
 moduleNameMapper: {
   '^measuretool-googlemaps-v3$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/measuretool-googlemaps-v3/dist/gmaps-measuretool.umd.js',
 }
```

Add these lines to your `jest.config.js` file. Hope it will work for you!